# Unable to edit data in feature dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing

When I click on Start Editing button following error occurs:

> Could not edit the data in the folder or database you selected. The featureclass is currently in load-only mode.

What do I need to do to start editing?

Currently I am not able to do editing in ArcMap, ArcGIS 9.2 and data is an enterprise geodatabase stored in Oracle 10gR2.

I do data migration on electric dataset while loading data into existing dataset on database server. When I imported data in ArcMap, after clicking on Start Editing, the following error highlighted:

> Could not edit the data in the folder or database you selected. The featureclass is currently in load-only mode.

Comment: Are you editing using ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro or something else?  Is your data in an Enterprise Geodatabase?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [edit] the question to specify the exact version of ArcGIS in use, your license level, and the RDMBS of your enterprise geodatabase.  Either an error occurred during initial loading, or one of your feature classes was explicitly left in load-only I/O mode. If the former, you should address that before editing. The latter can be addressed by placing the layer in normal I/O mode (building spatial indexes)

Comment: Yowza!  You have some seriously ancient software in use. Unfortunately there are a tremendous number of potential issues, and few who can remember back nine major releases ago. Did you try placing the layer in normal_io load mode?

Comment: @Vince-Could you please tell me how to put dataset from load only mode to normal i/o mode in arcgis 9.2?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is much more likely a secondary error, where the load failed, and that's why the layer remains in LOADONLY_IO, so just toggling the layer is either the wrong solution or can't work. There's a huge repository of archaic ArcSDE information over in the old Esri Forums. Have you tried searching on the error message and reviewed any of the hundreds of results from GeoNet? Similarly, a search on "how to place an ArcSDE layer in normal io mode" should return scores of options.